# How to use from keyword : in ethers.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

In web3.js we will use **from** keyword as below, in the same way, how can we use **from** keyword in ether.js

eg: web3.js ==>>aggregator.methods.withdraw( ).send(**{ from: this.state.account }**)

ethers.js ==>> How to use **from** keyword??

Answer (score 0):

In ethers, after creating a contract instance, you can send an options object as last atribute of a function call.

```
let contract =  new ethers.Contract(address, abi, signer);

// waits until transaction is submitted.
let transaction = await contract.withdraw({ from: this.state.account });

// waits until transaction is finished.
await transaction.wait();
```